# iOS MapBox Callout offset not working, callout always appear at the same height

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapbox

It seems that despite me providing a value in the offset property for the callout, it still appears at exactly the same position. This position is a little too high above the flag images that I am displaying.

UIImage *markerImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Flag.png"];
marker = [[RMMarker alloc] initWithUIImage:markerImage anchorPoint:CGPointMake(0.45, 0.9)];

marker.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0.5);

//also tried 
[marker setCalloutOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0.5)];

marker.canShowCallout = YES;

marker.delegate = self;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because unlike anchor points in MapBox iOS SDK, callout offset is absolute value, for example if you want to show callout offset at 28 pixels above the the anchor point, you have to set: `marker.calloutOffset=CGPointMake(0, 28);`

if that didn't help, try setting `marker.contentsCenter` too.

Hope it helps ;)